# How to modify DataGridView apprearance

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two questions:

1. How to not show column headers in DGV?
2. How to delete left part(the thing that allows you to select every value in row) in DGV?

Answer (score 2):

What you want are 2 properties: `ColumnHeadersVisible` (used to show/hide the column headers) and `RowHeadersVisible` (used to show/hide the row headers);

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify below property false.

```
RowHeadersVisible 
ColumnHeadersVisible
```